# Linux command for distcp time

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am trying to use intra-cluster distributed copying by distcp -

/homeappl/home/user/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop distcp file:///wrk/user/random.file file:///wrk/user/output18

Is there any command to find out how much time is taken for the distributed copying to take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash command `time` or find the job in the jobtracker/yarn and it will say how long it took.

```
time hadoop distcp file:///wrk/user/random.file file:///wrk/user/output18
```

Comment: Actually, I am new to this, but how do I find the job in jobtracker/yarn?

Comment: Assuming your network/VPN/DNS is setup correctly the easiest way is the CTRL + Click on the link that is output by running the job.  Otherwise you'll have to know what the URI and port is as per your particular cluster configurations.